# Problem with Python scheduler, can´t get it to execute function every night

Tags: python, time, schedule

In my program I have a scheduler that I can´t get to work. It´s supposed to run a function every night at 00:10 for a web scraper. (def scrape() below) If I change the scrape function to a simple function like this it runs and print out to console every night.

```
def testTime():
    print("test schedule")
```

But if I run my program looking like this it´s won´t do the scrape every night. If I restart the program and run it everything is fine and I get my data into my variable "fixed_scrape" but restarting the program every day isn´t how I want it.. It´s running on a Raspberry Pi.
What am I´m missing or doing wrong? Have read something about using Ischedule insted but won´t get it to work either.. I´m new into Python...

```
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Value
from optparse import Values
import re, requests, ast
from prompt_toolkit import print_formatted_text
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from heapq import nsmallest
import schedule
import pip._vendor.requests

HoursPerDay = 10
PriceLimit = 80

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW) 




def scrape():
    r = requests.get('https://www.elbruk.se/timpriser-se3-stockholm')
    return dict(zip([i[0] for i in re.findall(r"'((2[0-4]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9]))'", r.text)],
            ast.literal_eval(re.search(r"data: .*(\[.*?\])[\s\S]+(?='Idag snitt')", r.text).group(1))))
    
fixed_scrape = scrape()


def cheap():
    my_dict = fixed_scrape 
    cheapest_hour = nsmallest(HoursPerDay, my_dict, key=my_dict.get)
    return [(i.removesuffix(':00')).lstrip('0') or 0 for i in cheapest_hour]


def threshold():
    price_hour = fixed_scrape
    price_hour = {k:v for k,v in price_hour.items() if v < PriceLimit}
    dick = nsmallest(24, price_hour, key=price_hour.get)
    return ([(i.removesuffix(':00')).lstrip('0') or 0 for i in dick])


schedule.every().day.at("00:10").do(scrape)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    now_time = time.strftime("%H")
    cheapest_hours = cheap()
    cheap_threshold = threshold()
    print(cheapest_hours, "Are the cheapest hours today")
    print(cheap_threshold, "Hours when price is under" , PriceLimit, "öre/kwh. (Buying on threshold)")
    
    
    print("Active hour now is: ",now_time)
    
    if now_time in cheap_threshold:
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)

    elif now_time in cheapest_hours:
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)

    else:
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW) 
    
time.sleep(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I got the solution with implementing this and run it in a separate thread. Seems to work so far.

```
def run_continuously():
    cease_continuous_run = threading.Event()
    class ScheduleThread(threading.Thread):
        @classmethod
        def run(cls):
            while not cease_continuous_run.is_set():
                schedule.run_pending()
    continuous_thread = ScheduleThread()
    continuous_thread.start()
    return cease_continuous_run

def background_job_1():
    logging.info("Background 1 thread running...")


#schedules new scrape with prices from site every day
if __name__ == "__main__":
    format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO, datefmt="%H:%M:%S")
    logging.info("Main - starting thread")
    schedule.every(30).seconds.do(background_job_1)
    schedule.every().day.at("00:10").do(scrape)
    schedule.every().day.at("03:00").do(scrape)
    schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(scrape)
    stop_run_continuously = run_continuously()
    logging.info("Main: completed !!")
    time.sleep(10)
    #stop_run_continuously.set()


#run the program
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```